# Is there an error in my query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am making a query in SQLite in iOS and sometimes it returns 0 rows. Is there any errors in it?

```
SELECT mcon.MessageDictKey, 
       mcon.EMail, 
       con.Name, 
       con.ShowOnLists, 
       mcon.ContactType
  FROM MessageContacts AS mcon
  LEFT JOIN Contacts AS con ON mcon.EMail=con.EMail 
 WHERE mcon.MessageDictKey='5-131' 
   AND mcon.ContactType=0
```

Comment: Without knowing more information about your tables, we can't tell whether there's a problem with the query or not.

Comment: it depends. Did you use double quotes or single quotes to surround your query?

Comment: Assuming the email fields are defined similarly in both tables, there aren't any 'errors' - the query will work just fine.  The real question is, what do you WANT it to return?

Comment: "Sometimes" is extremely odd behaviour, given that your conditions are constant...

Comment: It must return a single row. I definitely know, that my application logic does not allow 0 rows for such queries. In some cases it still returns 0 rows... I think, the problem is indeed in quotes or joining by e-mail...

Comment: `sometimes it returns 0 rows` which there could be no data from database to return

Comment: Then show an example of the data in the tables that you think should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your query is reversed.  I believe what you want to select from Contacts and LEFT JOIN to MessageContacts.  You always want the contact back, even if they don't have any messages.  YOur query is saying "I always want messages, even if they don't have a contact" which is backwards.

```
SELECT mcon.MessageDictKey, 
       mcon.EMail, 
       con.Name, 
       con.ShowOnLists, 
       mcon.ContactType
  FROM Contacts AS con
  LEFT JOIN MessageContacts AS mcon ON mcon.EMail=con.EMail  AND mcon.MessageDictKey='5-131' AND mcon.ContactType=0
```

I also moved your WHERE clause to the ON statement.  Putting it in WHERE would basically cause the LEFT JOIN To act like an INNER JOIN (as unmatched records would be forced have a value to pass your WHERE clause).

If this isn't what you want, then tell me and I will remove my answer.  I couldn't convey all of this accurately in a comment, so I submitted it as an answer.

Comment: This didn't work. Still I plused this, because it was useful, thanks.

Comment: Then I think you need to expand your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish.  What's in the tables in question and what are you looking for?  Which table is the "master" (i.e. has all the records you want) and which might only not have any records (i.e. 0 or more related records based on the Email)?